# Microsoft IDEs, source file encodings, BOMs and the Unicode character \uFEFF?

Tags: c#, unicode, character-encoding, whitespace

We have parsers for various Microsoft languages (VB6, VB.net, C#, MS dialects of C/C++).

They are Unicode enabled to the extent that we all agree on what Unicode is.  Where we don't agree, our lexers object.

Recent MS IDEs all seem to read/write their source code files in UTF-8... I'm not sure this is always true.  Is there some reference document that makes it clear how MS will write a souce code file?  With or without byte order marks?  Does it vary from IDE version to version? (I can't imagine that the old VB6 dev environment wrote anything other than an 8 bit character set, and I'd guess it would be in the CP-xxxx encoding established by the locale, right?)

For C# (and I assume other modern language dialects supported by MS), the character code \uFEFF can actually be found in the middle of a file.  This code is defined as a zero-width no-break space.    It appears to be ignored by VS 2010 when found in the middle of an identifier, in whitespace, but is significant in keywords and numbers.    So, what are the rules?   Or does MS have some kind of normalize-identifiers to handle things like composite characters, that allows different identifier strings to be treated as identical?

Comment: It's unclear from your question if your stuff is conforming to the language spec... for example I believe C# is UTF-16 by default

Comment: UTF-8 and UTF-16 aren't different except how the characters are stored.  Direct experimentation with VS2010 shows that saving a new file gets you an UTF8 file, and that when reading a file with no BOM, that the IDE assumes the character coding is UTF-8.  Yes, our stuff is language conforming to the extent we have a good definition of the language.  I'm asking where this is this, if it is, or if not, what people actually know.

Comment: ... re UTF-8 ... our tools read files according to their "apparant" or declared encoding, and convert the characters to UTF-16 internally as they are read.  So, our C# parser only sees UTF-16 characters.  We're having trouble knowing what the encoding of a file produced by various IDEs are, when they aren't specifically byte order marked.   We're having trouble with the code point \FEFF found in the *middle* of a file, too.

Answer (score 4):

This is in a way a non-answer, because it does not tell what Microsoft says but what the standards say. Hope it will be of assistance anyway.

### U+FEFF as a regular character

As you stated, U+FEFF should be treated as BOM (byte order mark) in the beginning of a file. Theoretically it could also appear in the middle of text since it actually is character denoting a zero width non-breaking space (ZWNBSP). In some languages/writing systems all words in a line are joined (=written together) and in such cases this character could be used as a separator, just like regular space in English but it does not cause a typographically visible gap. I'm not actually familiar with such scripts so my view might not be fully correct.

### U+FEFF should only appear as a BOM

However, the **usage of U+FEFF as a ZWNBSP has been deprecated** as of Unicode version 3.2 and currently the purpose of U+FEFF is to act as a BOM. Instead of ZWNBSP as a separator, U+2060 (word joiner) character is strongly preferred by the Unicode consortium. Their [FAQ also suggests](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#bom6) that any U+FEFF occurring in the middle of a file can be treated as an unsupported character that should be displayed as invisible. Another possible solutions that comes into my mind would be to replace any U+FEFF occurring in the middle of a file with U+2060 or just ignore it.

### Accidentally added U+FEFF

I guess the most probable reason for U+FEFF to appear in the middle of text is that it is a an erroneous result (or side effect) of a string concatenation. RFC 3629, that incorporated the usage of a BOM, denotes that stripping of the leading U+FEFF is necessary in concatenating strings. This also implies that the character could just be removed when found in middle of text.

### U+FEFF and UTF-8

U+FEFF as a BOM has no real effect when the text is encoded as UTF-8 since it always has the same byte order. BOM in UTF-8 interferes with systems that rely on the presence of certain leading characters and protocols that explicitly mandate the encoding or an encoding identification method. Real world experience has also showed that some applications choke on UTF-8 with BOM. Therefore the usage of a BOM is generally discouraged when using UTF-8. Removing BOM from an UTF-8 encoded file should should not cause incorrect interpretation of the file (unless there is some checksum or digital signature related to the byte stream of the file).

Answer (score 1):

On "how MS will write a souce code file" : VS can save files with and without BOM, as well in whole bunch of other encodings. The default is UTF-8 with BOM. You can try it yourself by going File -> Save ... as -> click triangle on "Save" button and chose "save with encoding".

On usage of FEFF in actual code - never seen one using it in the code... wikipedia suggests that it should be treated as zero-width space if happened anywhere but first position ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark ).

Comment: Sure, that's what Wikipedia says. And it is pretty vague, what does "treat it as zero width space" mean??  I want know what *Microsoft* says, reference to chapter and verse.

Answer (score 0):

For C++, the file is either Unicode with BOM, or will be interpreted as ANSI (meaning the system code page, not necessarily 1252). Yes, you can save with whatever encoding you want, but the compiler will choke if you try to compile a Shift-JIS file (Japanese, code page 932) on an OS with 1252 as system code page.

In fact, even the editor will get it wrong. You can save it as Shift-JIS on a 1252 system, and will look ok. But close the project and open it, and the text looks like junk. So the info is not preserved anywhere.

So that's your best guess: if there is no BOM, assume ANSI. That is what the editor/compiler do.

Also: VS 2008 and VS 2010, older editors where no to Unicode friendly.
And C++ has different rules than C# (for C++ the files are ANSI by default, for C# they are utf-8)

Comment: What do you mean by "Unicode wirh BOM"?  UTF-8, UTF-16, and UTF-32 are all representations of Unicode.  (The misuse of "ANSI" to refer to a Windows-specific code page makes me suspect you mean UTF-16, but it's hard to be sure.)

Comment: By "Unicode with BOM" I meant UTF-16 and UTF-8 with BOM (Windows has no support for UTF-32, not even for conversion). And yes, the BOM for UTF-8 does not act as BOM, but as "encoding marker". For "ANSI code page" seem misused, but it is not my misuse, it is the  Windows lingo. Windows uses "ANSI code page" to mean "current system code page" (so even 932, the Japanese code page, can be "ANSI code page"). It is indeed a misnomer, but that is not my fault.